# Adobe Reader parameter-controlled search function not using ß

Tags: parameters, adobe-reader

i've already asked this on the adobe forums but nobody seems to have had this problem in the past, so i'm gonna try here:

situation:

i have a pdf-file (http://www.groneick.de/martinsmarkt.pdf) in which i want to search for an occasion of "außergewöhnlich"

```
C:\Users\username>cd c:\

c:\>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /A search=außergewöhnlich c:\martinsmarkt.pdf
```

given the case the pdf-file is at c:\

what happens is, the adobe reader software is searching for occurences of "auergewhnlich".

i have found that there seems to not be any difference between a->ä / ö->o / ü->u, but what about the "ß"? (saying i could search for "ubernaturlich" and it would find "übernatürlich" aswell)

using "ss" for "ß" doesnt do the job, neither does "s" instead of "ß"

i am really really stuck on this one ... so i would be very glad if somebody could point me towards a solution.

here is the thread inside the adobe forums:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/5292731#5292731

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though it's not the root of the problem i have now "solved" the problem by telling the hosting c#-program to fill the search-form the hard way by controlling the up-popping adobe reader

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is the terminal, assuming that you are interacting with a prompt your cmd is probably filtering and encoding your text in the wrong way.

I should also remind you that a pdf can contain a lot of stuff, and often times it's not clear plain text, so searching for *words* in a pdf doesn't really makes sense most of the time if you don't know how to do it and what your program of choice is really doing, Acrobat Reader circumvent this issue adopting an OCR if the PDF it's not plain text but this doesn't works that great in my experience.

Comment: if i use the "strg+f" search-functionality of adobe reader everything works fine, and there's no problem with ß or any other non-american character